# Why doesn't the printout of this program stop at the 0 digit?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ char* key="844607587";

 while(*key!=0){
 printf("hello world,%c\n",*key);
 key++;}
}
```

Why doesn't the program stop at the zero digit?  Then what does the 0 mean? the one without ' '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a simple mistake - you are comparing the (most likely ASCII) characters in your string with the numeric value 0. Change:

```
while(*key!=0){
```

to

```
while(*key!='0'){
```

Note that The numeric value 0 is the value of the C string terminator, often written as `'\0'`, so your code stops when it reaches the end of the string, rather than when it sees the character `'0'`.

Comment: then what does the 0 mean? the one without ' '.

Comment: The numeric value 0 is the value of the C string terminator, often written as `'\0'`.

Comment: @SongZhibo- There is a distinction between the glyph 0 (that is, the circle you write to denote the number 0) and the ASCII value 0.  The glyph 0 has ASCII value 48.  If you don't put quotes around a 0, C interprets what you're writing as "the character with ASCII value 0," which isn't the character literal `'0'`.

Answer (score 4):

`while(*key!=0)` should be `while(*key!='0')` to skip zero. `key` is string so `*key` will be char and you are trying to compare `*key` with integer zero not character zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're comparing each character to the number 0, which is not the same as the character '0'.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing key to the 0 char or (null) character, instead of the 48 or the 0 character, try `''`

```
while(*key!='0')
```

Or

```
while(*key!=48)
```

Answer (score 0):

The character `'0'` is different from the numeric value 0. In [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `'0' == 32`

If `key = "8446\07587"` then `while(*key!=0)` will work fine, but since you're dealing with characters you'll need to compare characters instead

```
while (*key != '0')
```